# accidentally dragged .java file out of eclipse, can't drag back in

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I accidentally dragged a .java file out of the package view onto the desktop. Now when I try to drag it back into the package it says "problems occurred copying selected resources" and "a resource already exists on disk" (and then the file pathway to my workspace) even though the file is no longer shown in the package view. How can I get the .java file back into the package and what exactly happened when i dragged the file onto the desktop? Also for some reason when I dragged the file to the desktop it created a duplicate of the file with the date in the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved it by going into my workspace in finder and deleting the file. for some reason it was still there just not showing up in the package view in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not worth figuring out "what happened"...

1. Create a new java class in Eclipse where the old one was
2. Open the original file (now on the desktop) in a text editor
3. Copy the entire contents
4. Paste it into the new java class
5. Move on

Comment: that was the first thing I tried but it says "Type with same name but different case exists"